# Puppet Error: 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at

Tags: networking, puppet, syntax

I am getting a syntax error when running puppet, although I cant figure out why:

**Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Syntax error at 'String'; expected ')' at /etc/puppet/modules/riak/manifests/init.pp:17**

Here is the init.pp file:

```
# == Class: riak
#
# Deploy and manage Riak.
#
# === Parameters
#
# [*$package_name*]
# [*$service_name*]
# [*$manage_package*]
# [*$manage_repo*]
# [*$version*]
# [*$ulimits_nofile_soft*]
# [*$ulimits_nofile_hard*]


class riak ( 
  String[1] $package_name       = $::riak::params::package_name,
  String[1] $service_name       = $::riak::params::service_name,
  Boolean $manage_package       = $::riak::params::manage_package,
  Boolean $manage_repo          = $::riak::params::manage_repo,
  String[1] $version            = $::riak::params::version,
  Integer $ulimits_nofile_soft  = $::riak::params::ulimits_nofile_soft,
  Integer $ulimits_nofile_hard  = $::riak::params::ulimits_nofile_hard,
  Hash[String, Variant[String, Boolean, Integer]] $settings = {},
)
inherits ::riak::params {
  if $manage_repo and $manage_package {
    include ::riak::repository
  }
  if $manage_package {
    include ::riak::install
    Package[$::riak::package_name] ~> File[$::riak::params::riak_conf]
  }
  class { '::riak::config': } ~>
  class { '::riak::service': } ->
  Class['::riak']
}
```

Any ideas where the Syntax error is coming from?

Answer (score 4):

The data type declaration is new to puppet 4; are you perhaps attempting to use this on a puppet 3.x or earlier puppet master?

Comment: i am using puppet versions  3.8.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 Agent, and  3.6.1 on Ubuntu 14.10 Master.  Should I upgrade? thanks

Comment: I don't know that I can recommend an upgrade (it's not a simple upgrade, having just gone though it), but it's either that or rewrite the module to not use Puppet 4 syntax.  Also, it is worth noting that puppetlabs recommend your master be the same or newer than your agents (or they used to; I haven't seen it written down for a while).

Comment: Master needs to be same or newer version. Puppet 4 masters generally won't work with Puppet 3 agents, although the latest versions of `puppetserver` have renewed support for Puppet 3 agents.

Comment: I was able to enable future parser, and that solved some of the problems.  I have new errors now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should delete the last "," in your param declaration for something like that :

```
class riak ( 
  String[1] $package_name       = $::riak::params::package_name,
  String[1] $service_name       = $::riak::params::service_name,
  Boolean $manage_package       = $::riak::params::manage_package,
  Boolean $manage_repo          = $::riak::params::manage_repo,
  String[1] $version            = $::riak::params::version,
  Integer $ulimits_nofile_soft  = $::riak::params::ulimits_nofile_soft,
  Integer $ulimits_nofile_hard  = $::riak::params::ulimits_nofile_hard,
  Hash[String, Variant[String, Boolean, Integer]] $settings = {}
)
```